# Show that if $\lim_{z\to\\z_0}f(z)$=0 and there is a positive M such that |g(z)|$\leq$M for all z in some neighborhood of $z_0$, then

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

$\lim_{z\to\\z_0} f(z)g(z)$=0.

This is for complex analysis, and I know how to do this argument for regular epsilon calculus arguments. We want to say since $\lim_{z\to\\z_0} f(z)$=0 then we can take 
$|f(z)-0|<\frac{e}{M}$ whenever $0<|z-z_0|\delta$. Okay I know we need to have an argument where we take $\delta=\min\{blah,blah\}$ maybe? But the underlying algebra is,

$|f(z)|*|g(z)| = |f(z)*g(z)-0|<\frac{e}{M}$*M =$\epsilon$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Since $f(z) \to 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$|z - z_0| < \delta \implies |f(z)| < \frac{\epsilon}{M}$$

Now what can you say about $|f(z)g(z)|$ for $|z - z_0| < \delta$?

Comment: Hahah, I forgot to put $\epsilon$/M * M = $\epsilon$

Comment: so what do we have to set $\delta$ equal to or are we just done...I'm sorry complex analysis arguments like this are new to me.

Comment: @Crypto The $\delta$ is the same throughout the argument. If $|z - z_0| < \delta$, then $|f(z)g(z)| < \epsilon$ and we're done. The only thing we have to do in this sort of argument is prove the *existence* of $\delta$, which we've done.

Comment: I was thinking that you have |f(z)-0|<$\epsilon$ when 0<|z-$z_0$|<$delta_1$ and |g(z)|$\leq$M when 0<|z-$z_0$|<$delta_2$ then you take $delta$=min{$delta_1$,$delta_2$}, now we can proceed with the algebra.

Comment: @Crypto Yes, that's the full details of the argument. In practice, we could simply assume that $\delta$ is small enough to guarantee that $|g| < M$.